# Else statement is called after return in recursive call

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to recursively remove items with same value from the list. It is partially works, but when it reaches to return, it still executed else statement after it and returns None.
I am interested to accomplish this recursively.

```
def remove_from_list(item, lst):
    if item not in lst:
        return (item, lst)
    else:
        lst.remove(item)
        nw = lst[:]
        remove_from_list(item, nw)

lst = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 41] 

remove_from_list(6, lst)
```

Any clues why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you return the value returned by the recursive call, your function will return the modified list instead of None:

```
def remove_from_list(item, lst):
    if item not in lst:
        return (item, lst)
    else:
        lst.remove(item)
        nw = lst[:]
        return remove_from_list(item, nw)
```

A bit of explanation:

In python, every function returns None when the end of the function is reached. I've modified your code to make this easier to understand:

```
def remove_from_list(item, lst):
    if item not in lst:
        return (item, lst)
    else:
        lst.remove(item)
        nw = lst[:]
        remove_from_list(item, nw)
    return None
```

Here, the result of the call `remove_from_list(item, nw)` is neither stored, nor returned, so it is 'lost', and python continues to the `return None` statement.

Comment: yes, that works, thanks @rulerofthehuns. Can you help me to understand why this is happening, seems when it reaches to return it should stop further execution, right?

Comment: In python, every function returns None when the end of the function is reached. In your code, the result of the second remove_from_list() call was not returned, so the execution continued to the end of the function, where None was automatically returned.

Comment: @rulerofthehuns, I think you should move the commented explanation into your answer as it definitely highlights why the code is working. Also, welcome to SO :)

Comment: I've modified my answer as @HarisNadeem suggested.